# Win7 ~ Windows Firewall service could not start - error code 1068

Tags: windows-7, firewall

Attempting to start the Windows Firewall service in Windows 7 results in:

Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.

Nothing malicious reported back from Malwarebytes and Microsoft Secrity Essentials full scans.

I've tried performing a Windows Update and a few  registry things to no avail.

Any pointers to resolving this greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

R.

Comment: Is ICS running?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear that something it needs is not starting, so look at this screen shot of the items that it is dependent on, and make sure they are started, and set to automatic. If not one will not start, post back about that service, because that is the real problem, not the firewall.

[image]

Comment: I've ensured all these dependent services are started automatically but Firewall still refuses to start. Could my Windows Firewall Authorization Driver be missig or corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I have a windows 7 pc that I experienced the same error (1068) on recently (Feb2019). This was just after a reboot after an avast update (not sure if it was related), along with multiple blue screens. I then disabled all services and selected them in bunches till the blue screen of death disappeared, but in the end I was still left without a firewall. I researched high and wide and decided to try the following and actually fixed the issue without registry changes or OS recovery or re-installs.

1. I simply booted to "safe mode"
2. Opened a file window and went to the path C:\Windows\System32
3. Right clicked and highlighted on services.msc and elected "Run as Administrator"
4. Scrolled down into the services and highlighted "Base Filtering Engine"
5. Right clicked and selected "Properties" (new window opens)
6. Changed 'startup type' to "Automatic" from the picklist
7. Selected the "Apply" button,
8. Closed the "Properties" window
9. Closed the services.msc window and then rebooted

Note: my account has administrative rights to start with, so I believe you'll need this capability first before using "Run as Administrator"

I hope this helps someone out there who has the same situation. I won't guarantee the firewall will be fixed in all versions of windows, but it's worth a shot trying first before executing any of the more involved alternatives.